# Whats the diffrerence between Maximum Connection Reuse Time and Time-To-Live Connection Timeout in Oracle 11g (11.2)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Whats the diffrerence between Maximum Connection Reuse Time and Time-To-Live Connection Timeout in Oracle 11g (11.2) ?. I could not able to find the difference in Oracle documentation,

Are they both same ?

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/optimize.htm#autoId10

Comment: You link gives differences between them. Do you want better example or explanation?

Comment: well, it just striked in my mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you.

Comment: Sorry for that.. I started doing it

Answer (score 0):

The time-to-live timeout is basically how long a checked-out connection can be kept before it is returned to the pool. On the other hand a connection that is not checked out and is idle for Maximum connect reuse time will be closed.